# Python typing for a tuple

Tags: python, typing

I am simply trying to define typing for a tuple in python 3.85. However, neither approaches in the [documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html) seem to properly work:

```
Tuple(float,str)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-7964c1934b1f>", line 1, in <module>
    Tuple(float,str)

  File "C:\Users\kinsm\anaconda3\lib\typing.py", line 727, in __call__
    raise TypeError(f"Type {self._name} cannot be instantiated; "

TypeError: Type Tuple cannot be instantiated; use tuple() instead
```

VERSUS:

```
tuple(float,str)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-29-fea16b9491a0>", line 1, in <module>
    tuple(float,str)
result:
TypeError: tuple expected at most 1 argument, got 2
```

Comment: Your link clearly used square brackets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```py
from typing import Tuple

### ---- Examples ----- ###
Tuple[float, float]
Tuple[float, str]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from typing import Tuple

out = Tuple[float,str]
print(out)

x: Tuple[int, str, float] = (3, "yes", 7.5)
print(x)
```

output:

```
typing.Tuple[float, str]
(3, 'yes', 7.5)
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: when defining typing elements you use [] not ()